# PHP JSON into javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

befora I ask this i tried every solution on google and here on stackoverflow.

So in my js file I have this

```
    var locations = [
    ['Name','Country','City','lat','lng'],
    ['Name','Country','City','lat','lng'],
];
```

When i wrote this in file manually my mapp shown locations but I need to generate content of locations variable from mysql in php, is there something that I missing.I tried with ajax,console.log...etc

My PHP file

```
    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT hospital_name,country,city,lat,lng FROM hospitals");
$to_encode = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
  $to_encode[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($to_encode);
```

I tried this but no success

```
$.getJSON( "process.php", function( json ) {
  var locations = json;
 });
```

Comment: Where's the attempted code?

Comment: Ajax will do what you need, have a look at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/ . It gets  automatically parsed to a JS array

Comment: var location should be defined outside of the getJson function

Comment: I edited code still doesn't work, where do I wrong?

Comment: Try to console.log(json)

Comment: @PHPglue getJson is a wrapper for a specific type of AJAX call. He should be able to get this to work... unless something else is wrong.

Comment: Unless I am blind I am not seeing a website... nor am I seeing raw JS. His return is likely JSON `echo json_encode($to_encode)` the problem is probably in how they are trying to use the JSON once he has it. I agree with @aldrin27... they should be logging the output so we can see exactly what is being returned. However, It is obvious by what was included as a hardcode example that the user is expecting one thing while his returned JSON is obviously different.

Comment: Got it. What kind of error are you getting in PHP? Some kind of query issue is my guess.

Answer (score 1):

I just switched your `mysqli_fetch_row` to `mysqli_fetch_array`

```
    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT hospital_name,country,city,lat,lng FROM hospitals");
    $to_encode = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      $to_encode[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($to_encode);
```

Comment: Please add explanation not just code. It now becomes a game of `find the difference` whereas a simple explanation of what you changed goes a long way helping others see it and understand why. Your code solution might be great....but the answer is very low quality without people being able to review it quickly